# MySQLConnection has no implementation

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, mysql-connector, connector-net

I'm new to C# and connecting to databases.
The problem is: whenever I try to connect to DB by running this code:

```
        string connparams = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test;";
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connparams);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException me)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(me.ToString());
        }
          connection.Open();
          connection.Close();
```

I get the window "The application is in break mode"
When I take a look at the events window I can see an exception with description "No source code". When I try to see the implementations of functions in MySQLConnection I can see none of them, only declarations. So what should I do/redo/reinstall in order to solve this? Using VS2017, .NET Framework 4.6.1, Connector/NET (MySQL)

Comment: What framework are you using?  Asp.net standard, Asp.net core or something else?

Comment: Simply .Net Framework 4.6.1 in VS2017

Comment: Are you following Mysql docs or Asp.net to make the connection?

Comment: Yep, tried this one https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html - the same situation

Comment: Ok, I know you said Framework A.6.1 but when you picked a project which feature did you use?  There are numerous options under an a.6.1 framework, one is ASP.net core and another is Asp.net standard.  I am asking because I know how to connect it in Core but not so much the other ways.

Comment: If it is Core, this link will connect an app to mysql. https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-mysql-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: I picked Console Application(.Net Core). If I understood you correctly

Comment: Thank you, your link worked out

Comment: I am glad it all worked out for you.